# WCF + sending linq generated objects

Tags: wcf, linq, entityset

i have entities generated from my .dbml. So some objects have relationship "one to many" and in entities it was generated as EntitySet.

Also, I have WCF Workflow Service Application which contains .xamlx with bussines logic.

So using this .xamlx i try to send objects which was genereted before to client, but i catch an exception "The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly".

EntitySet<> was added to KnonwTypes. Serelzation mode in .dbml file has "None" value.

So, could you tell me how i can solve this problem?

Comment: UPDATE: I changed serilixation mode to Unidirectional and it works, but have next problem, for one of object some properties was not defined with DataMemberAttribute and a not see it in client... How i can solve it?

Comment: Marc_s, how can i add this attribute if code is generated by visual studio ?

Comment: You could use an alternative method to generate your classes, which supports that kind of thing - e.g. [Damien Guard's Linq-to-SQL T4 templates (free)](http://l2st4.codeplex.com/) or [CodeSmith's PLinqO framework](http://www.codesmithtools.com/product/frameworks) (which requires a license of CodeSmith to use)

Comment: But basically, if you have the `SerializationMode = Unidirectional` the built-in Linq-to-SQL designer should do this, too, automatically. Maybe you need to delete that table from your model and re-add it again so that it'll pick up that `[DataMember]` attribute...

Answer (score 0):

is there an inner exception?

my guess is an circular reference caused by the navigation properties.

if that's that case you have a couple of options:

- <strike>remove the virtual keyword from your navigation properties and eager load everything.</strike> Note: not sure if this applies to linq to sql.
- map your entities to simple dto objects.
- employ a circular reference aware serializer (the one built in to .net is not).

Comment: Yes, inner excption exist, stacktrace of inner exception:    at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)

Comment: I thout about simple objects... but it so hard to map all objects, and i think it's silly do it when i have ADO.NET...

Comment: http://automapper.codeplex.com/ or http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/ make life easier